# How to create a column which flags (1 - weight loss;0 - same weight a) weight loss (8% or more) from previous measurement based on groupby of id?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, where-clause

I have a dataframe df:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"CLIENT_ID": [8222, 8222, 8222, 8222, 8300, 8300, 8300, 8300, 8300],
                   "ENCOUNTER_DATE": ['2020-01-01', '2020-03-02', '2020-04-18', '2020-07-31', '2017-06-10', '2017-09-11', '2018-02-01', '2018-04-01', '2018-05-31'],
                   "WEIGHT_KG": [56, 58, 50, 54, 71, 72, 74, 75, 65]})
```

which is sorted by `CLIENT_ID` and `ENCOUNTER_DATE`

| CLIENT_ID | ENCOUNTER_DATE | WEIGHT_KG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8222 | 2020-01-01 | 56 |
| 8222 | 2020-03-02 | 58 |
| 8222 | 2020-04-18 | 50 |
| 8222 | 2020-07-31 | 54 |
| 8300 | 2017-06-10 | 71 |
| 8300 | 2017-09-11 | 72 |
| 8300 | 2018-02-01 | 74 |
| 8300 | 2018-04-01 | 75 |
| 8300 | 2018-05-31 | 65 |

I want to create a `WEIGHT_LOSS` flag column which is 1, if the current `WEIGHT_KG` is at least 10% lower than the previous measurement and 0 if it is not, for each `CLIENT_ID` resulting in the table below:

| CLIENT_ID | ENCOUNTER_DATE | WEIGHT_KG | WEIGHT_LOSS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8222 | 2020-01-01 | 56 | 0 |
| 8222 | 2020-03-02 | 58 | 0 |
| 8222 | 2020-04-18 | 50 | 1 |
| 8222 | 2020-07-31 | 54 | 0 |
| 8300 | 2017-06-10 | 71 | 0 |
| 8300 | 2017-09-11 | 72 | 0 |
| 8300 | 2018-02-01 | 74 | 0 |
| 8300 | 2018-04-01 | 75 | 0 |
| 8300 | 2018-05-31 | 65 | 1 |

There probably is easy answer with `df.assign`, `np.where` or list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can`groupby` client and use `pct_change` on the "WEIGHT_KG" column:

```
df['WEIGHT_LOSS'] = (df.groupby('CLIENT_ID')
                       ['WEIGHT_KG']
                       .pct_change() # calculate percent change
                       .lt(-0.1)     # loss if lower than -0.1 (-10%)
                       .astype(int)  # convert True/False to 1/0
                     )
```

output:

```
   CLIENT_ID ENCOUNTER_DATE  WEIGHT_KG  WEIGHT_LOSS
0       8222     2020-01-01         56            0
1       8222     2020-03-02         58            0
2       8222     2020-04-18         50            1
3       8222     2020-07-31         54            0
4       8300     2017-06-10         71            0
5       8300     2017-09-11         72            0
6       8300     2018-02-01         74            0
7       8300     2018-04-01         75            0
8       8300     2018-05-31         65            1
```